# Im looking for R function to import values from one data excel sheet to another excel sheet with each value with interval of 33 rows in new sheet

Tags: excel, loops, member-functions, data-import

Hi i want to create a matrix for my analysis.
I have example data here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMmry.png).
Im looking for R function how i can import values for each year with interval of 33 rows in new excel sheet. for instance value for 1990 is in Col b Row 2 and value for 1991 should go in same col Row 34 and so on.

Thanks in advance.

I tried looping with interval but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.